# Firebase signInWithPopup problem with Angular Chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angularfire2

I'm developing a Chrome extension with Angular and AngularFire. My issue is that when I use the signInWithPopup method, to sign in the user the popup closes which causes the auth to fail.

I know that I can't keep the popup open artificially when it loses focus, therefore I'm stuck.

If I open the Developer Tools that keep the popup open and the sign-in and the subsequent redirect works.

Any idea how to tackle this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the docs again, I realized, that this won't work as the auth should be initiated from the background script. So instead of using AngularFire, I found that by using the Firebase JS SKD I can achieve this, as I was unable to get it to work with AngularFire.